# Windows ETW: Kernel consumer receives no EventCallback or BufferCallback events

Tags: delphi, winapi, etw

i am trying to listen to ETW kernel events.

- Step 1: Call [`OpenTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), specifying the [`EventCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363721%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and optional [`BufferCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363685%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions that will be called during my call to [`ProcessTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

  ```
  var
      logFile: EVENT_TRACE_LOGFILE;
      currentTrace: TRACEHANDLE;
  begin
      ZeroMemory(@logFile, sizeof(logFile));

      logFile.LoggerName := KERNEL_LOGGER_NAME;
      logFile.LogFileName := 'C:\Users\Ian\foo.etl';
      logFile.ProcessTraceMode := 0;
      logFile.EventCallback := RealtimeEventCallback;
      logFile.BufferCallback := BufferCallback; //optional

      currentTrace := OpenTrace(@logFile);
      if (currentTrace = INVALID_PROCESSTRACE_HANDLE) or (currentTrace = -1) then
             RaiseLastWin32Error();
  ```
- Step 2: [Enable kernel events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363691%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is done by calling [`StartTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In my case i want to trace kernel [interrupts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa964780%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([`EVENT_TRACE_FLAG_INTERRUPT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and [deferred procedure calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa964748%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([`EVENT_TRACE_FLAG_DPC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

  ```
  var
      sessionProperties: PEVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES;
      bufferSize: Int64;
      th: TRACEHANDLE;
      loggerName: string;
      logFilePath: string;
  begin
      loggerName := KERNEL_LOGGER_NAME;
      logFilePath := 'C:\Users\Ian\foo.etl';

      bufferSize := sizeof(EVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES)
          + 1024 //maximum session name is 1024 characters
          + 1024; //maximum log file name is 1024 characters

      sessionProperties := AllocMem(bufferSize);
      ZeroMemory(sessionProperties, bufferSize);

      sessionProperties.Wnode.BufferSize := bufferSize;
      sessionProperties.Wnode.ClientContext := 1; //QPC clock resolution
      sessionProperties.Wnode.Flags := WNODE_FLAG_TRACED_GUID;
      sessionProperties.Wnode.Guid := SystemTraceControlGuid;
      sessionProperties.EnableFlags := EVENT_TRACE_FLAG_INTERRUPT or EVENT_TRACE_FLAG_DPC;
      sessionProperties.LogFileMode := EVENT_TRACE_FILE_MODE_CIRCULAR;
      sessionProperties.MaximumFileSize := 5;  // 5 MB
      sessionProperties.LoggerNameOffset := sizeof(EVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES);
      sessionProperties.LogFileNameOffset := sizeof(EVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES)+1024;

      //Copy LoggerName to the offset address
      MoveMemory(Pointer(Cardinal(sessionProperties)+sessionProperties.LoggerNameOffset), PChar(loggerName), Length(loggerName)+1);

      //Copy LogFilePath to the offset address
      MoveMemory(Pointer(Cardinal(sessionProperties)+sessionProperties.LogFileNameOffset), PChar(logFilePath), Length(logFilePath)+1);

      hr := StartTrace({var}th, PChar(loggerName), sessionProperties);
      if (hr <> ERROR_SUCCESS) then
            raise EWin32Error.Create(SysErrorMessage(hr));
  ```

  And the log is started sucessfully (i can see `foo.etl` begin to grow to its 5 MB circuluar limit).
- Step 3: Call [`ProcessTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which blocks until it has delivered all pending events to the [`EventCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363721%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) handler specified in Step 1:

  ```
  var
     res: LongWord;
  begin
     res := EventTrace.ProcessTrace(@currentTrace, 1, nil, nil);
     if (res <> ERROR_SUCCESS) then
        raise EWin32Error.Create(SysErrorMessage(res));
  ```

Except that `ProcessTrace` repeatedly returns immediately, and no callback is called - even though the etl file is present and growing.

---

If i change the logging from **File Based** to **Realtime** logging:

- Step 1 - `OpenTrace` changes to support *realtime*:

  ```
  logFile.ProcessTraceMode := PROCESS_TRACE_MODE_REAL_TIME;
  ```
- Step 2 - `StartTrace` changes to support *realtime*:

  ```
  sessionProperties.LogFileMode := EVENT_TRACE_REAL_TIME_MODE;
  ```

In this case `ProcessTrace` ***never*** returns, but neither `EventCallback` or `BufferCallback` are ever called.

What am i doing wrong?

---

**Update:** My callback functions:

```
function BufferCallback(Logfile: PEVENT_TRACE_LOGFILE): LongWord; stdcall;
begin
   ShowMessage('BufferCallback');
   Result := 1; //return true to keep processing rows
end;

procedure RealtimeEventCallback(pEvent: PEVENT_TRACE); stdcall;
begin
   ShowMessage('EventCallback');
   nEvents := nEvents+1;
end;
```

Comment: In my experience (at least with real-time tracing), OpenTrace() always "succeeds" even if the session doesn't exist.  It is only when you call ProcessTrace() that it fails with ERROR_WMI_INSTANCE_NOT_FOUND.  I don't know how the kernel provider behaves, but with custom real-time providers you need to StartTrace() before OpenTrace().  I assume the same is true when tracing events to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the problem.

The headers i was using were not quad-word aligned.

In Delphi parlance, the keyword `packed` was being used.

Answer (score 0):

You can't provide both LoggerName and LogFileName.  If you supply a LoggerName, LogFileName must be null.  See [this link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363780%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)