# how does event tracing and event logging works in terms of real-time event consumption

Tags: windows, winapi, events, logging, event-log

I am newbie to windows events I was wondering how I could consume events in real-time as new events are generated. So i need to know in simple terms how event tracing and event logging works

Answer (score 0):

Simple google search will find examples...

http://blogs.iis.net/eokim/archive/2009/05/15/consume-iis-etw-tracing.aspx

[How to consume real-time ETW events from the Microsoft-Windows-NDIS-PacketCapture provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470135/how-to-consume-real-time-etw-events-from-the-microsoft-windows-ndis-packetcaptur)

https://www.google.com/search?q=event+tracing+for+windows+consume+events+example